# Rails render partial with data from params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to render a partial from the controller (ajax request to controller which renders partial so JS can insert into DOM).

Code for the partial is simple. It requires an object

**View**

```
= render "partials/foo", object: @bar
```

**Partial**

```
= object.name
```

This works fine from the view. But when I try this from the controller (passing `params` in as the object) I get the error **undefined variable `object`**

**Controller**

```
render "partials/foo", object: params[:data]
```

`params[:data]` is just a `hash`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with `:object`, as it will expect a variable with the same name as the partial (minus the underscore). You can rename the variable using the `:as` option.

if you set `render partial: "foo", object: @foo` you will have a variable `foo` in the partial.

It is the same as `render partial: "foo", locals: { foo: @foo }`

---

You can use `:locals`, so you can set a hash of objects in your partial. Assuming that `params[:data]` is a hash:

```
params[:data] = {a: 'something', b: 'another thing'}
render "partials/foo", locals: params[:data]
```

In your partial you will be able to use the variables `a` and `b`.

---

Or, you can define your own variable if `params[:data]` has a simple value:

```
params[:data] = 'something'
render "partials/foo", my_variable: params[:data]
```

In your partial you will be able to use `my_variable`.